# Highchart Pie Chart label size in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying, from within the Wordpress plugin wpDataTables, to change the size of the labels in my Pie Chart since they are way too small. However, I'm not sure how the code should look and the only thing the code below does is hide all the charts on the Wordpress page I embed it on...

What am I missing? I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with this line:

```
obj.options.series.pie.label.minFontSize: 14, null;
```

But what?

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    if (typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined') {      wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; }
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[3] = function(obj) {
        obj.options.series.pie.label.minFontSize: 14, null;        
        }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`minFontSize` is a property so you want to assign a to a value to it using `=`.

`obj.options.series.pie.label.minFontSize = 14;`

I assume you got confused looking at [the HighCharts docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.label.minFontSize)

> minFontSize: number, null
>
> For area-like series, allow the font size to vary so that small areas get a smaller font size. The default applies this effect to area-like series but not line-like series.
>
> Defaults to null.

This doc is saying the `minFontSize` property can be either a `number`, **or** `null` and that `null` is the default value.

Comment: Sadly, the above solution doesn't work. I'm not sure what is wrong but setting a minimum font value doesn't change anything. I'm assuming that either it's because the script going through the wpdatatables plugin or some other scaling is interfering.